# Unable to create indexes using solrj4.0 and solr4.0

Tags: solrj

I added SOLR to my existing webapp. When I query the SOLR data from the
browser it is returning zero records (this is expected since there is nothing there). But when I try to add documents using HttpSolrServer no indexes are created and no exceptions are thrown. When I request update url from a browser it looks good.

Every time I run my program to create indexes a `write.lock` file is created in my solr data folder but again no indexes created.

Comment: Showing your code will increase the likelihood of a helpful response.  Also, please clarify "When I request update url from a browser it looks good." -- does this mean you are seeing the data?

Comment: Also, what platform is the server running on?

Comment: this is what i mean url: protocol://host:port/solrtest-1.0.0/update?commit=true and response is   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?> 
- <response>
- <lst name="responseHeader">
  <int name="status">0</int> 
  <int name="QTime">33</int> 
  </lst>
  </response>  i am running it in my local machine windows 8 tomcat 6

Comment: write.lock file gets created when i run the above update url also and gets deleted automatically when i shutdown tomcat..

Comment: my code SolrServer solrServer  = new HttpSolrServer(server);
 SolrInputDocument doc = new SolrInputDocument();
doc.addField("id", someID); 
.
.
.
.
solrServer.add(doc);
solrServer.commit(); and this was working fine with solr3.3, i just updagraded to 4.0 made necessary changes in solrconfig.xml and schema.xml

Comment: Hi problem resolved some where in my code i am accidentally overriding my solr home by writing...system.setproperty... working fine after commenting that... thanks much for your responses..